# Apply folder settings globally in KDE4

Tags: kde, opensuse, file-manager, konqueror

Im running opensuse 12.1 with KDE 4.8.4.
I've made settings changes to the Konquerer shell in a specific folder (e.g. changed my view from compact to details).

How do I persist these settings that I change in one folder and make it apply to all folders?
Windows has such a button on the folder options->View tab.

Answer (score 0):

Open Konqueror
Go to View -> Adjust View Properties
There will be a group panel with a title of "Apply View Properties To"
One of the options is "All Folders"
Select the above mentioned option and press ok or apply